# Under what assumption is the following statement true: $f(x) < 0$, then there exists a constant $k > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq -k$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

I wish to justify the following statement using a set of weak assumptions, e.g. continuity, closedness. We assume a standard metric space $\mathbb{R}^n$,

> Given $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, suppose  $f(x) < 0, \forall x \in D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then there exists some $k > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq -k, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash D$. What property makes this hold true?

I suspect this is either an assumption on $D$, e.g., $D$ is closed and/or bounded, or an assumption on $f$, e.g., $f$ is continuous, or both (continuous over closed).

Comment: The behaviour of $f$ on $D$ is generally speaking completely unrelated to its behaviour on $\Bbb R^n\setminus D$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Looking again I think we can safely assume $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The only assumption that comes in mind is really strong - $D$ needs to be dense and $f$ needs to be continuous such that $f\leq -k$. This is obviously not very useful.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yeah, I've added another assumption (which makes everything much less practical anyway)

Comment: @Cauchy'sCarrot $f$ being $\alpha$-Holder continuous for some $\alpha>1$, plus $D\ne\emptyset$, is a sufficient condition. :P

Comment: Do you want $f(x) \leq -k$ on $D$ or its complement? It looks like a pretty bad question the way you have stated it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy as stated, it is on the complement. I'm sorry that it is a bad question, the source is even worse

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I will reformulate it and ask again some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even taking $D$ to be closed and $f$ to be continuous is insufficient. If $\Bbb R^n\setminus D$ has non-empty interior, any continuous real-valued function on $\operatorname{cl}D$ can be extended to one that takes a positive value somewhere in $\Bbb R^n\setminus D$. If, on the other hand, $D$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$, and $\sup_{x\in D}f(x)=0$, there is no $k>0$ such that $f(x)<-k$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus D$.

I doubt that any reasonable conditions will give you what you want.